# Scala code doesn't compile when importing Kotlin

Tags: scala, kotlin, gradle

I have Java and Scala in the same module and I'm trying to migrate the Java code to Kotlin.

The sources are like this:

```
src
  - main
    - java
      - extendedModel
        - LayoutSemantics.java
    - kotlin
      - ExtendedProperties.kt
    - scala
      - ...
```

ExtendedProperties.kt is

```
package extended

val outLayout = "outLayout"
val outShapes = "outShapes"
```

In Java code, I write

`import static extended.ExtendedPropertiesKt.getOutLayout;`

and it compiles correctly. However, in Scala code the line

`import extended.ExtendedPropertiesKt.getOutLayout`

looks good in intelliJ, but gradle build says

`[ERROR] UniLayerLoader.scala:29:8: not found: object extended`

And this is my build.gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'altair.dnn.conv.scala-library-conventions'
    id 'jacoco'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.8.0'
}

    
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.7"
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.21.10'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.1'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.3'
}
```

Comment: Probably Scala is being compiled before .class generated by Kotlin become visible to it. But someone more knowledgeable about Gradle and its plugin would have to respond how to control that order.

Comment: According to Gradle, I see compileKotlin, then compileJava, and only the compileScala, so it doesn't seem this is the case.

Comment: Then there might be a thing that Scala plugin is configured to rely on classpath from Java or Scala, but Kotlin would have to be explicitly added to it.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I configure it correctly?